# show tasks 1-5 depending on what day it is

Tags: python, schedule

i'm just a 15 yr old kid messing around with python, i don't really know much about it. i hope my description is thorough enough.

So, I have 5 'tasks', and depending on what day it is, I want it to pull up the task.

(Sunday- task 1, Monday- task 2,... then on Friday it will go back to task 1 and so on)

I'll make the initial date Sunday, 4/1/2012.

I can make python display the current date with:

```
import datetime
from time import strftime 
print strftime("%A, %b %d %Y")
```

but thats all i could really do on my own :/

can anyone help me make it display the 'task' depending on what day it is when i open the program?
 i know alittle about defining things, if and while statements and simple stuff if it helps... thanks
(sorry if the answer is already in another post or something..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  So you can read from the documentation that strftime takes a format and an optional second argument which is what time to print.  The time defaults to localtime().  So, start with that:

```
now = localtime()
print now
```

localtime() returns a struct_time object, which is documented here: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time .  You can see that it contains the information you want: its sixth field is tm_wday, "range [0, 6], Monday is 0."

Now you can index into a dictionary of tasks (however you represent those, I'll assume as strings for now, but they could be functions or anything else).  Maybe something like this:

```
tasks = {
    0: "Stuff to do on Monday.",
    1: "Stuff to do on Tuesday.",
    2: "Stuff to do on Wednesday.",
}

print tasks.get(localtime().tm_wday, "Nothing doing.")
```

Whoa, what is that?

We created a dictionary using the special syntax `{}`, mapping weekday numbers as defined for struct_time, and we indexed into it, printing whatever we found.  But if nothing was found, we print "Nothing doing."  This is explained in the documentation for the `dict` class: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict - get() is a method that takes a key and an optional second value which is the default to return if the key is not found.  This is useful if you have nothing to do on certain days but don't want an error to be raised on those days.

**Edit:**

OK, so I understand now that you want to start from today (1 April 2012, noting that 4/1/2012 is ambiguous because Europeans write dates differently than Americans).  Today you want to do Task 1, tomorrow 2, and seven days from now you'll have wrapped around and be on Task 3.

This sounds like a job for the modulo (remainder) operator, `%`.  Whenever you want to cycle through some set of integers (e.g. your tasks) based on a potentially larger set of integers (e.g. calendar days), modulo arithmetic may be useful.  In this case you fundamentally want something like this:

```
tasks = [ 'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5' ]
print tasks[calendar_day % len(tasks)] # len(tasks) is 5
```

So long as `calendar_day` is a number that increments by one each day, this will index into the list of tasks using modulo arithmetic such that you'll start with the first one, go stepwise to the last, then wrap back to the first, etc.

How to determine calendar_day?  Well, the field `tm_yday` of `struct_time` that we saw earlier looks useful--it's the day of the year, from 1 to 366 (on leap years, 365 otherwise).  So:

```
tasks = [ 'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5' ]
print tasks[localtime().tm_yday % len(tasks)]
```

Today is actually day number 92, and 92 % 5 is 2, and Python uses zero-based indexing, so the above would choose Task 3 for today.  If you really want today to be Task 1, just add the appropriate fixed offset:

```
tasks = [ 'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5' ]
print tasks[(localtime().tm_yday - 2) % len(tasks)]
```

But if you want perfect results, you may realize that 366 is not evenly divisible by 5, so after leap years you'll see a "jump" in your tasks list on January 1.  And if your task list had a different length, you might experience problems more often when the year changes.  Dealing with time in a precise way is quite a difficult task in practice, and I'd invite you to open a new question about this specific issue (and link to it in a comment here) if you care about that level of detail.

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot! the only thing is that the tasks aren't designated to each day, because 0 wont be a Monday task next week. (maybe i'm your'e right and im just interpreting your work wrong) but this is definitely getting me progress!

Comment: Ah, so you want to rotate through the 5 tasks on all 7 days?  I see now.  I'll add something to my answer shortly.

Comment: Yeah! that sounds great! all these pythondocs probably have the answers im looking for, i just feel like deciphering 'programmer language' is still so hard to do (as of now)

Comment: you rock! ill probably do as you say and open another question, but ill worry about that at a later time. my only question is how do i work in the start date (1 April 2012)? when i ran what you posted, i got 'task 3' as an output, sorry that im asking for so much by the way. I want to be able to do more of this on my own

Comment: I added something to make it so today is Task 1.  It's not super-elegant (you could do it fancier by explicitly constructing a date of 1 April 2012 and doing math from there), but it's good enough for our purposes now I think.  Don't underestimate how hard it can be do do programming with dates & times: http://www.fastcompany.com/blog/kit-eaton/technomix/microsoft-zune-outage-caused-leap-year-glitch http://www.informationweek.com/news/cloud-computing/infrastructure/232602382 http://apple.slashdot.org/story/11/01/02/0225235/iphone-alarms-hit-by-new-years-bug

Comment: wow i cant believe it was that simple (in my case, at least)
and thats crazy! they must have a lot of programmers working on those too!